# Dictionary to global environment python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have attempted to open a list of cvs files in a loop using python. I started with the idea to open the files to a dictionary as I been told to do not attempt to dynamically create names on the fly, I tried the following code

### Load all csv files

```
 filenames = ["broaderRelationsSkillPillar.csv","ISCOGroups_en.csv"]

 dataframes ={}    ## create a dictionary
```

## Create the list of three DataFrames: dataframes

```
for i in filenames :
    dataframes[i] = pd.read_csv(i)
```

### until here it all happens smoothly.

```
for k ,v in dataframes.items():
    [k] = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dataframes[k])
```

note - my issue happens here ,my result here is only one of the 2 data frames

would I be able to open this csv files directly froma loop and name them on the fly? I have around 20 csv's and I'm trying to automate a bit the code. tks

### Question edited to facilitate support

### create dictionaies

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]} 
a = {'col3': [1, 2], 'col4': [3, 4]} 
c = {'col3': [1, 2], 'col4': [3, 4]}
```

### Pass to a data frame

```
d= pd.DataFrame(data=d)
a= pd.DataFrame(data=a)
c= pd.DataFrame(data=c)
```

### create a list of dataframes

```
filenames = [a ,d ,c]
```

### create a dictionary of dataframes

```
dataframes ={}    ## create a dictionary 

for i in filenames :
    dataframes[i] = i

del a , c, d
```

### from a dictionary of data frames back to data frames ( here is where i failed , why?)

```
for k ,v in dataframes.items():
    k = pd.from_dict(dataframes[k])
```

Comment: Are the content of all csv files same? Why don't you loop `data_list` instead and have indiviudal dataframe, you can concat them if you want to.

Comment: `[k] = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dataframes[k])` why the brackets around `k`? what are you trying to do here?

Comment: Also... why `read_csv` twice and then `from_dict`... can't you just stop at `dfs = {fname: pd.read_csv(fname) for fname in filenames}` ?

Comment: What's the point of your second loop? Why pass a data-frame to `pd.DataFrame.from_dict`?

Comment: @i tried to create the dataframes in a loop initially but it did not work. But when i tried to pass all to a dictionary worked. But then o thought , ok , how do i know unpack this dictionary of data frames...2 skills in one hit:)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga  unpack the data frames from the dictionary of data frames

Comment: Why  would you want to do that. You just said you want to avoid using dynamic variables (which I think is a good idea). Anyway, it failed because you simply assigned your dataframes to `k` in a loop. It simply kept the last value from the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe need `dict comprehension` for dictionary of DataFrames with keys by filenames:

```
dataframes = {i:pd.read_csv(i) for i in filenames}
print (dataframes['broaderRelationsSkillPillar.csv'])
print (dataframes['ISCOGroups_en.csv'])
```

Or is possible removing last `.csv` by indexing:

```
dataframes = {i[:-4]: pd.read_csv(i) for i in filenames}
print (dataframes['broaderRelationsSkillPillar'])
print (dataframes['ISCOGroups_en'])
```

---

Sample DataFrames:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a','a'],'B': list(range(2))})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'C': ['b','f','s'],'D': list(range(3))})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'E': ['f','g','h'],'F': list(range(3))})
print (df1)
   A  B
0  a  0
1  a  1

print (df2)
   C  D
0  b  0
1  f  1
2  s  2

print (df3)
   E  F
0  f  0
1  g  1
2  h  2
```

Created `dictionary of DataFrames`:

```
dataframes = {'file1':df1, 'file2':df2, 'file3':df3}
print (dataframes)
{'file1':    A  B
0  a  0
1  a  1, 'file2':    C  D
0  b  0
1  f  1
2  s  2, 'file3':    E  F
0  f  0
1  g  1
2  h  2}
```

For `DataFrame` select by `key` - ere by `file1`:

```
print (dataframes['file1'])
   A  B
0  a  0
1  a  1
```

In loop `v` is `DataFrame`:

```
for k ,v in dataframes.items():
    print (k)
    print (v)
    print (type(v))
file1
   A  B
0  a  0
1  a  1
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
file2
   C  D
0  b  0
1  f  1
2  s  2
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
file3
   E  F
0  f  0
1  g  1
2  h  2
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

If want modify `DataFrames` in loop, you need to reference the original `df` by using `key` of `dictionary`:

```
for k ,v in dataframes.items():
    #modify df - e.g. add `a` to first column
    v.iloc[:, 0] = v.iloc[:, 0] + 'a'
    print (v)
    dataframes[k] = v
    A  B
0  aa  0
1  aa  1
    C  D
0  ba  0
1  fa  1
2  sa  2
    E  F
0  fa  0
1  ga  1
2  ha  2
```

`Dictionary of DataFrames`:

```
print (dataframes)
{'file1':     A  B
0  aa  0
1  aa  1, 'file2':     C  D
0  ba  0
1  fa  1
2  sa  2, 'file3':     E  F
0  fa  0
1  ga  1
2  ha  2}
```

Check one `DataFrame`:

```
print (dataframes['file1'])
    A  B
0  aa  0
1  aa  1
```

Comment: my big question is ; let say i have 10 data frames in a dictionary, how do i unpack all 10 to the global environment individually?

Comment: @Ian_De_Oliveira - Hmmm, why it is necessary? Do you need join all `10` together? Because if use `dataframes['ISCOGroups_en.csv']` it is like `df`, check it by `print (type(dataframes['ISCOGroups_en.csv'])`

Comment: as usual thanks. I will try this morning, no no need to join them together. I'm more interested how to extract df's from a dictionary of data frames in a loop.

Comment: @Ian_De_Oliveira - I try explain more with sample data, if still something not clear let me know.